# Can't call servlet post method

Tags: jsp, servlets, post

I want to call `doLogOut` servlet's `post` method, but each time i call servlet, `Get` method has been called instead of `post` method!

Here is my `jsp` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title> Checkout </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="doLogOut">
            <p style="text-align: right;">
                <a href="doLogOut"> LogOut </a>
            </p>
        </form>
         ...
</html>
```

And here is my `doLogOut` servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/doLogOut"})
public class doLogOut extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet doLogOut</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h3> Get method: </h3>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet doLogOut</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h3> Post method: </h3>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

But i see `Get method:` message in result, Why?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on `<a href="..." />` performs GET request by default. You should either submit your form or perform ajax request with POST method. Here is an example to describe the idea:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title> Checkout </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function logoutWithAjax() {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "doLogOut",
              success: function() {
                console.log("Logged out");
              }
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" method="post" action="doLogOut">
            <p style="text-align: right;">
                <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"> LogOut with Form Submit</a>
                <a href="javascript:{}"  onclick="logoutWithAjax();"> LogOut with Ajax Request</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using bootstrap's button class `btn-link` in order to use your submit button as a link.

```
<form method="post" action="doLogOut">
     <p style="text-align: right;">
          <button type="submit" class="btn-link"> LogOut </button>
     </p>
<form>
```